# What is the shape of the envelope of all orbits with velocity of equal magnitude at their intersection?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

Also known as: where can I go with my delta-v budget?

[For parabolic trajectories in uniform gravity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30402/parabolic-envelope-of-fireworks), the answer is a parabola.

Thats why I'm surprised that the same envelope for elliptical orbits around a point mass seems to have a more complicated shape.

Numerical approximation of the envelope for orbits around a point mass $A$, passing through $B$ with velocity $v=1$:
[image: egg envelope]

Some kind of egg shape? Rather curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the answer is just a plain old ellipse, the numerics were wrong.

**Construction:**

With a point mass $A$ and location $B$, one calculates the greatest apoapsis obtainable in the degenerate case, the point $D$.

For all orbits, the second focus, $A_2$, must lie on the circle $c$ with centre $B$ and radius $BD$.

For all locations of $A_2$, the extreme point $F$ is on the intersection of the ellipse with foci $A$ and $A_2$ going through $B$, with the ray from $B$ through $A_2$

All those pssible locations of $F$ forms the envelope $e$, which is an ellipse with foci at $A$ and $B$, with semi-major axis $\frac{AD + BD}{2}$

[image: construction]

No egg shapes for me :(